# How to use a Web API to manage my Users in an Asp.net core MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-core

I have one simple question but so far I didn't find the answer.

Is it possible to run an Asp.Net Core MVC project with Authentification and NO DATABASE.

My goal is to use a Web API with JWT and I want to use the MVC project to use the Web API to manage my Users (login, subscribe, etc.). Is it possible ?

So far I'm stuck, I search everywhere and I've already been searching for several days. So now I'm confused with all the conflicted knowledge I have. Between the UserStore, RoleStore, and all the stores possible.

I created both

```
    public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser<string>>
    public class MyRoleStore : IRoleStore<IdentityRole<string>>
```

Thanks to the comment of @abdusco I corrected the services calls

```
services.AddScoped<IUserStore<IdentityUser<string>>, MyUserStore>();
                services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<IdentityRole<string>>, MyRoleStore>();
                services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(cfg => {
                    cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                })
                        .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
                        .AddRoleStore<MyRoleStore>();
```

Now I can compile but I cannot run my application. I have this error :

```
"Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
```

'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator
Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' : Implementation type 'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomUserStore' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]') (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator
Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' : Implementation type 'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomUserStore' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]') (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]  Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'
: Implementation type
'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomUserStore' can't be converted to service type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]') (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]
Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' : Implementation type 'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomUserStore' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]') (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]  Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
: Implementation type
'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomUserStore' can't be converted to service type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]') (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]
Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' : Implementation type 'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomRoleStore' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]') (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]  Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomUserStore' : Implementation type 'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomUserStore' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]') (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]  Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomRoleStore' : Implementation type 'MyProject.CustomProvider.CustomRoleStore' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]')"

Comment: Would the user info be coming from a separate API, then?

Comment: You're off to a good start with a custom `IUserStore`, why didn't it work for you?

Comment: Note that there's a `UserStoreBase` abstract class to start from if you're trying to implement raw `IUserStore`. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/746b9f82fb5c026ce3ce1aed9b2883078ca9ebe6/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs

Comment: Thank you for the info. Yes my goal is to let the API share the information.

Comment: I will implement this Interface since you advise for it. That's said. I really need to know Is it possible to do all this without any database ? Because when I want to register my service, I guess that it will still ask for a DbContext for EntityFramework ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it without a DB. You'll already be implementing `IUserStore` by inheriting from `UserStoreBase`. It provides some implementation for you, leaving only the methods dealing with data retrieval as `abstract`. You only need to implement those methods and fetch the actual info from an API.

Comment: Thanks you ! Then What is the correct way to register it in the services ?

Comment: `services.AddScoped<IUserStore, CustomUserStore>()` then  `.AddUserStore<CustomUserStore>()` like you have there.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions. Thank you so far. I'm still stuck because of the error I included in the new edit of my question. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: The error is about resolving your user store by the interfaces it should have implemented. If should implement [all the interfaces listed here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/746b9f82fb5c026ce3ce1aed9b2883078ca9ebe6/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs#L23-L34). If you've inherited from `UserStoreBase`, this is already done by the base class.

Comment: `class MyUserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser<string>>`  -> `class MyUserStore : UserStoreBase<IdentityUser<string>, other, types, here>`: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/746b9f82fb5c026ce3ce1aed9b2883078ca9ebe6/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs#L22

Comment: I'll add these steps as an answer.